# Drupal - How to show a map with many markers and a paginate listing

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, drupal, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to have a view grouping a google map with more than 5000 markers and the listing of the node. The listing has to be paginate (around 50 results per page) but the google map has to show all the markers. Exposed filters can be used to filter both the map and the listing.

I've managed it using Views and GetLocations, but I've a huge problem : the page takes minutes to load and crash in IE (8,9,..). I've tried using MarkerCluster but no change..

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the data out of Drupal and try to do it with pure HTML and JS for Google Maps API first, does the browser take that long to load and still crash? I don't think it's a front-end issue but a back-end related to the number of records you're pulling.

My guess is that your Views are not cached. Views are very intensive since they're mangled SQL queries. https://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache
http://www.millwoodonline.co.uk/blog/drupal-7-performance-gains-with-views-cache

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this module, but I'm already using the Boost module.. And the problem is that IE crash once the page is rendered, loading the google maps